Which is correct, "What exam have you had today" or "What exam did you have today"?
If somebody completed an exam at six pm and it is already nine pm, should I say "What exam have you had today" or "What exam did you have today"?

The latter sounds more natural to me.

What exam did you take today?  And since it's done and dusted, I would use the simple past.

Most fluent English speakers would say, "What subject did you have today?" It doesn't matter how long it's been since the person took the class, whether it was 10 minutes ago or 10 hours ago. Indeed if it was 5 years ago, you'd still say the same thing, except instead of "today" you'd say whatever time period.

Sorry, I didn't see your answer. I changed "subject" in the OP's example to "exam" because it matches the situation "If somebody completed an exam at six pm…" I figured that you can complete an exam but not a class subject. Topic? Maybe.

@Mari-LouA As an American, I would not ask someone, "What subject have you had today?", but "What class did you attend today?" But I was assuming this was some other dialect and a point that was not worth getting into.

I'd probably use Present Perfect (What exam have you had today?) if and only if I was expecting the answer might be relevant to addressee's current state.
For example, suppose I was asking my daughter, and I knew that she was apprehensive about at least one exam (an oral test in French, perhaps), so she might need some reassurance now that it's not the end of the world if you clam up from nervousness in something like that.
But if I was just asking in a polite "How was your day?" kind of way, I'd use "do-support" (What exam did you have today?), same as (almost) everyone else.

It's important to note the temporal specifier today in the question as presented. If instead I was asking about which exam the addressee had last Tuesday, I'd almost always only use the "do-support" version, not Present Perfect. But even with last month's exam, it's possible to contrive contexts where the answer might have a direct bearing on the current situation, in which case I might just use Present Perfect anyway.

Would it make any difference as to whether these tenses are used in the interrogative or affirmative forms? For example: "What exam did you have today?" - "Today I have had an oral test in French". Or one's daughter comes home and says: "I have had a very hard test in French today". Could the Past Indefinite work in these patterns, at least in British English?

If the speaker was the person who actually took the test earlier, they would know if they were going to continue with something like I've had a very hard test in French today, so I'm feeling a bit down. Can I have an ice-cream to cheer me up? That's pretty much all there is to it with Present Perfect. Unless what you're talking about has a direct bearing on the current situation in some obvious way (which is why you're bringing it up in the first place), don't use Present Perfect. And don't waste brain cells thinking about British or American English here.

...but note that there are almost no contexts where you MUST use Present Perfect in English, so when in doubt, DON'T. almost all non-native speakers overuse Perfect verb forms - probably because their teachers find it relatively easy to explain when you CAN use perfect forms, but they rarely point out that it's almost always optional. And the simple rules they teach don't accurately reflect how native Anglophones actually speak.

Thank you! What you have said is right to a tee. We are overusing such tenses as perfect and continuous ones. I think we use Present Perfect because what one is talking about has always a direct bearing on the current situation in his imagination. It happens because everything that I'm keeping in mind at the moment of speaking I regard as connected with my present mental activity=present situation. That is why Perfekt (Present Perfect) is almost always used in conversations in the German language notwithstanding its having the markers of past time.

Yes, it's easy to see why you'd think whatever you're talking about in the past is "relevant" to current time of speaking - why else would you be speaking about it in the first place? But it's important to note that in my example, the speaker's primary reason for speaking is I'm feeling a bit down. Can I have an ice-cream to cheer me up? The business about having had an exam earlier is really just "incidental" information that's specifically being mentioned because it's relevant.

I've always liked your answers because they are bringing up comprehension that, for no cognizable reason, english teaching books even of C1, C2 levels suggest a kind of pared-down grammar (that "today" comports only with Present Perfect, end of story). But the real language works in a more flexible and limpid way.
